# Show that these events are independent (dyadic expansions)

Tags: probability-theory, independence

This example is from Bauer's probability book:

Let $\Omega:=[0,1[$, $\mathcal{A}:=\Omega\cap \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $P:=\lambda_{\Omega}$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$. For every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let

$$A_n:=\Big[0,\frac{1}{2^n}\Big[\cup \Big[\frac{2}{2^n},\frac{3}{2^n}\Big[\cup \dots \cup \Big[\frac{2^n-2}{2^n},\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\Big[$$
The sequence $(A_n)$ of these events is independent: We have $P(A_n)=1/2$ for every $n$ and, as is easy to check,

$$P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n})=\frac{1}{2}P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_{n-1}}) \hspace{1cm}    (*)$$

whence $P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n})=P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_{n-1}})P(A_{i_n})=\dots=P(A_{i_1})\cdot... \cdot P(A_{i_n})$ for every finite set of distinct natural numbers $i_1,\dots,i_n$.

**Question:** How can I prove equation $(*)$? I was able to show it for two distinct indices $i_1,i_2$, but I don't see how to generalize to $n$ indices.

Why is $A_n$ the set all $x\in [0,1[$ whose terminating dyadic expansion has its $n$th digit equal to $0$?

EDIT: I tried to give an answer below. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To show independence we may assume WLOG that $i_1< \dots<i_n$. For each $n$ consider the grid of points in $[0,1]$ defined by

$$P_n:=\bigg\{\frac{k}{2^n}:k=0,1,\dots,2^n\bigg\}$$

Clearly, $P_{n}\subset P_{n+1}$, i.e. the grids are getting finer when $n$ gets larger. Each grid $P_{n}$ determines a set of $2^n$ half-open disjoint intervals in $[0,1)$ of the form $I^k_n=[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n})$ $k=0,1,\dots,2^n-1$. We see that $A_n$ is the disjoint union of those intervals having $k$ even, i.e. $A_n$ leaves out every other interval $I^k_n$ $k=0,1,\dots,2^n-1$. Hence each $A_n$ is the disjoint union of $2^{n-1}$ intervals of length $1/2^n$, and therefore has measure $1/2$. Note also that each point $\frac{k}{2^n} \in P_n$ with $k$ even becomes $\frac{2k}{2^{n+1}} \in  P_{n+1}$, and so points having an even numerator $P_n$  will still have an even numerator in subsequent grids.

What happens if we intersect $A_{i_1}$ and $A_{i_2}$ with $i_1<i_2$? Each of the $2^{i_1-1}$ half-open intervals of $A_{i_1}$ will be sub-divided into $2^{i_2-i_1}$ half-open intervals by the points in $P_{i_2}$, and $A_{i_2}$ leaves out every other such interval. So the result is a disjoint union of $2^{i_1-1} \cdot 2^{i_2-i_1-1}=2^{i_2-2}$ half-open intervals of the form $[\frac{k}{2^{i_2}},\frac{k+1}{2^{i_2}})$ with $k$ even.

If we intersect $A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}$ with some $A_{i_3}$ with $i_1<i_2<i_3$, then the same reasoning gives that $A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap A_{i_3}$ is a disjoint union of $2^{i_2-2} \cdot 2^{i_3-i_2-1}=2^{i_3-3}$ half-open intervals of the form $[\frac{k}{2^{i_3}},\frac{k+1}{2^{i_3}})$ with $k$ even.

Inductively we get that $A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n}$ is a disjoint union of $2^{i_n-n}$ half-open intervals of the form $[\frac{k}{2^{i_n}},\frac{k+1}{2^{i_n}})$ with $k$ even. Therefore the formula $$P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n})=\frac{1}{2}P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_{n-1}}) $$ is verified for $i_1< \dots<i_n$. Then induction gives us independence.

Finally $x\in[0,1)$ has a terminating dyadic expansion $(\varepsilon_j)$ with $n$th digit equal to zero if and only if $x\in\bigg[\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{\varepsilon_j}{2^j},\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{\varepsilon_j}{2^j}+\frac{1}{2^n} \bigg)=\big[\frac{k}{2^{n}},\frac{k+1}{2^{n}}\big)$ with $k$ even, i.e. if and only if $x\in A_n$.